# Ошибка при загрузке файла на сервер

Tags: php, файлы

Пытаюсь загрузить файл на сервер стандартными средствами.

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
..
<input type="file" name="f">
..
</form>
```

в массиве $_FILES содержится информация о темпе, однако move_uploaded_file возвращает false. В логах апача

```
May 16 22:55:00 2012] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.
[Wed May 16 22:55:00 2012] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-d' is not supported and will be ignored.
```

Гуглил, ничего конкретного не нашел

Answer (score 1):

1. включите 
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
2. Проверьте, есть ли загруженый файл, там откуда(tmp_name) вы пытаетесь его перенести.